# drupal aggregate JS files loses custom JS

Tags: drupal-7

I've completed a Drupal 7 site using the Adaptive theme and subthemes Corolla and Footheme. Everything is working well, but if I enable the aggregation of JS files, all my custom JS in my custom.js is gone,that is, it doesn't work. I've looked in the aggregated JS file, when turned on, and my JS is there, at the end of it. What? I haven't been able to find anything else about anyone having that problem. I can see in the order the JS files load, (if unaggregated) that my custom.js is last with the exception of the adaptivetheme_at_core/scripts/scalefix.js. So what gives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The horrors of drupal! Did you wipe all caches and run their update script? I've experienced similar things and usually it is fixed if I clear system cache and run their update before turning aggregate on. Somehow I doubt this will fix it for you but it's worth trying

Comment: other than the latest security update from Drupal (currently 7.22, update to 7.24 avail.), and Colorbox update (which they say may break things) I'm up to date. And yes, I've cleared the cache many times. I guess I could start turning off modules and see if that would work, but ... could take a while

Answer (score 0):

make 100% sure you replace .htacess file.